# Problems looping over a HashMap<String, String>

Tags: java, hashmap

I've got a basic HashMap. I'm trying to loop over it and get both the key and the value out of the Map. Here's what I have:

```
Map<String, String> myMap = versionExtractor.getVersionInfo();
for(String key : myMap.keySet())
    System.out.println(key);
    System.out.println(myMap.get(key));
}
```

The problem is that this won't compile. There is an error on the line that says `System.out.println(myMap.get(key));` that says:

```
java: class, interface, or enum expected
```

And the intelliJ IDE says: `Cannot resolve symbol 'key'`. The perplexing thing is that is resolved `key` without a problem in the preceding line that says `System.out.println(key);`. What's up with that?

Comment: I've updated my question with the correct code for reading values out of HashMaps.

Comment: Please don't change your original question, as it now makes all the current answers void. Better to update it, leaving the original there only.

Comment: The question hasn't changed, I just fixed a typo in the syntax. The question remains.

Comment: Ha... where's my opening `{`? lol... oh geez.

Comment: @quakkels you could add that as an answer and accept that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the opening brace on your `for` statement, so your second `println` is not part of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `myMap[key]`, you should use `myMap.get(key)`. It's a `Map`, not an array. BTW, if you want both *key* and *value*, you can rather iterate over the `EntrySet`:

```
for (Entry<String, String> entry: myMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    System.out.println(entry.getValue());
}
```

This saves extra hash calculation, and lookup on every iteration.

---

As it goes, the issue is something else. The missing `{` brace after your `for` statement, makes the closing `}` of `for` loop extraneous. Anyways, my original answer was with regards to your original question which used `myMap[key]` instead.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get a corresponding value for a given key, you should use the [get(Object key)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) method:

```
for(String key : myMap.keySet())
    System.out.println(key);
    System.out.println(myMap.get(key));
}
```

Even better, in order to iterate a Map, you can use the Map's `static Entry` class:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    System.out.println(entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question. the problem persists. I cannot use `key` more than once in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You're treating your Map like an array. That's not how Maps work. Use the Map.get(key) function instead.

For more info, check out the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html), which is the first result for googling "java maps".

Answer (score 1):

Given that you've got this:

> java: class, interface, or enum expected

I wonder if you're compiling with JDK 1.4, and you don't have the enhanced for loop of Java 5 available.

Once you've solved that, don't you want to loop over the Map.Entry objects, to avoid a redudant value lookup via `get()` ?

```
for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
   ...
```

Comment: I tried that with the same results. the `entry` will work the first time I use it but not the second.

Comment: I'm using 1.7... I found it. I'm missing an opening `{` after the `for()` statment. (smack myself in the forehead.)

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
Map.get(key)
```

Or

alternative look this example:http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-loop-a-map-in-java/

Comment: No you cannot , It will look for "key" key in the map and fails.